# How to Use jQuery Selector to Select Table Row Containing a Specific Link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm conditionally styling a table based on certain elements it contains. For example, the following code adds a class based on whether the tr contains the word 'Novel':

```
<script>$( "tr:contains('Novel')" ).addClass('row-highlight-novel');</script>
```

But what I'd like to do is the same thing, but with a link, where I could add a class to the tr based on whether it has a specific url or not.

I've tried `$("a[href='http://www.link-here.org/']")`, but that only selects the link, not the table row it's in. I can't seem to find the right selector that will do this for the whole table row. Your help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Tried `$("a[href='http://www.link-here.org/']").closest('tr')`?

Comment: That worked! Thank you!

Comment: ok, I posted it as an answer then

Answer (score 0):

Without further context I would think using `.closest()` would work:

```
$("a[href='http://www.link-here.org/']").closest('tr')
```

Ref: https://api.jquery.com/closest/

Answer (score -1):

This is how i would do it

html

```
<a href="http://test.com/?foo=bar&baz=quux"><tr>hello</tr></a>
<a href="http://example.ca/?foo=bar&baz=quux"><tr>hello</tr></a>
```

Jquery selector

```
$('a[href*="test"]').each(function() {
   $(this).addClass('test');
});
```

here is complete fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/q0nc3dzq/3/

Comment: Read the question again. The OP wants to select the row that the link is in, not the link itself which is what your code would do. There's also no need to use `.each()` in your answer as `$('a[href*="test"]').addClass('test');` would've been more efficient.

Comment: Yeah, the link is inside the table row.